# Ignoring file libSDL2.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64

Tags: c, arm, sdl-2, apple-m1

I have a M1 MacBook and I'm trying to add SDL2 libraries to my C project.

I always get this error message:

```
Ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.24.1/lib/libSDL2.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_gfx/1.0.4/lib/libSDL2_gfx.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
```

I tried changing the library path, header search path, also I reinstalled Xcode and the SDL libraries as well but it's always the same.

Comment: You're on an M1, so you _want_ to build for arm. But, for some reason, it's trying to build for x86. It finds the arm SDL2 library, which is good. But, what's bad is that it's trying to use a compiler/linker that is cross compiling for x86. The libraries are _not_ the problem. The compiler is. Although the default for most compilers is to compile for the _native_ arch, which is/should be arm, it's defaulting to x86. I'm not familar with Xcode. It may be defaulting to x86 [because many macs are x86?]. You may have to give it an option to build for arm? We'd need to see the compiler commands

Comment: Sorry but I'm also really new to Xcode, how can I send the compiler commands?

Comment: I don't have a Mac: M1, M2, x86, mc68000, or otherwise, so this is guesswork. AFAICT, `Xcode` is an IDE (i.e. it has a GUI interface). And, it seems it can build on any [supported] development platform and it can build/cross-build for any [other] _target_ platform. When you creating the project, one of the GUI menus should allow you to select the build target. You might be able to change this _after_ the initial project creation [hopefully] but the fallback is to create another project, taking care to select the correct options.

Comment: `homebrew` is _not_ part of `Xcode`, so I would have expected _it_ to mess up. But, it appears that `homebrew` is "smarter" than `Xcode`. For some/most IDEs, there is a "project creation" wizard that will guide you step-by-step. `Xcode` _should_ do the job, but if you _really_ get stuck, you could try another IDE (e.g. `Eclipse`, `Code::Blocks`, etc.). But, I'd bang on `Xcode` a bit more. I did a web search on: `Xcode project creation` and got 9M hits. Among them: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-an-xcode-project-for-an-app

Comment: Alright so I got it working by excluding x86_64 architecture and it can build the project, but now I get this error: the platform is not currently connected